# Cannot set props of custom Hook (React) dynamically

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, google-oauth, google-signin

How can I make the `hint` prop variable? I want it to have the email of the logged in user.

I tried by assigning `currentUser.email` (it's a state variable in the parent component). This doesn't work as it's always empty because that value is empty before logging in (when the `GoogleLoginButton` is created)

I tried with a state variable of the component that I set in the `updateUserInContext`. It doesn't work.

I tried to call `useGoogleLogin` directly in the callback of the `timeout` function and passing the configuration object. This object contains the `hint` prop updated with the correct user email. Reacts gives me a compilation error because `a Hook can be called only inside function components or custom hooks`.

So it's seems like I cannot make the configuration I pass to `useGoogleLogin` dynamic. The dependency I use is this one: https://github.com/MomenSherif/react-oauth.

It's not necessary to set the `hint` prop if there's only one google user logged in the same browser session.
If there are two users, I need to set it, otherwise, when refreshing the access token in the background, the app doesn't know which account to pick.

Do you know if there's a way to make `hint` dynamic?

Below the current code

```
export const GoogleLoginButton: React.FC<GoogleLoginButtonProps> = ({onSuccessfulLogin, onFailedLogin }: GoogleLoginButtonProps) => {

    const {currentUser, setCurrentUser} = useContext(LoginContext)

    const updateUserInContext = async (response: any) => {
        let googleUser = //logic to get google user info

        const user = new User()
        user.accessToken = response.access_token
        user.email = googleUser.email
        user.isUserLoggedIn = true
        setCurrentUser(user)
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            loginWithCurrentUser()
        }, 3  * 1000)
    } 

    let loginWithCurrentUser = useGoogleLogin({
            onSuccess: (codeResponse: any) => {
            updateUserInContext(codeResponse)
        },
            onError: (error:any) => {
            console.error(error)
            //Do other things on fail
        },
        hint: 'user@example.com',
        prompt:'none'}
    )
    
    const login = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: async codeResponse => {
            updateUserInContext(codeResponse).then(() =>{
               //Do other things on success
            }).catch(error => {
                //Do other things on fail
            })
        }, 
        onError: error => {
            console.log("error")
            // Do other things on fail
        },
        flow:'implicit'
    });
      
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => login()}>
                    Sign in with Google {' '}
            </button>
        
        </div>
    )
}

export interface GoogleLoginButtonProps {
    onSuccessfulLogin: Function,
    onFailedLogin: Function
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `hint` dynamically, just pass it as prop when calling `loginWithCurrentUser`

```
setTimeout(() => {
  loginWithCurrentUser({hint: user.email})
}, 50 * 60 * 1000)
```